# how change Spartacus Navigation menu with custom html

Tags: spartacus-storefront

**want to use this HTML**

*instead of spartacus OOTB cms html i want to change to following html structure*

````
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">THE ASSOCIATION</a></li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>
                   <a>WHO WE ARE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="">CONTACTS</a></li> 
        <li><a href="">PRODUCTS</a></li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>
                   <a>SHOES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a>UMBRELLAS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>          
   </ul>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to override the OTB component and you can access Navigation menu through:

   node$: Observable = this.service.getNavigationNode(
   this.componentData.data$
   );

data$: Observable = this.componentData.data$;

constructor(protected componentData:CmsComponentData,
protected service: NavigationService,
) { }

You can iterate node$ in template